# Plugin.BluetoothClassic How to receive full answer from device?

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I've got code from plugin:

```
byte[] bufferr = new byte[BufferSize];
  
if (!(await connection.RetryReciveAsync(bufferr, OffsetDefault, bufferr.Length)).Succeeded)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error", "Close");
}
else
{
    lbl.Text = ByteArrayToHexString(bufferr);
}
```

How can I get a complete response from the device? This code sometimes gives me a single digit, sometimes a full package of digits

Comment: What does device use as end of answer?  You have to read until the end of the answer.  The await does not know when the data terminated.  It waits for connection to close.  The device is processing data and may start a response but it may take time for response to finish.  Read the device documentation.

Comment: It depends. I just send 11 and the device gives me the string (or HEX string).

Comment: Is the string a c# string or a c++ string?  A c++ string terminates with a `\0.  Other types of strings may be preceded with a byte count.  You have to read the device manual to find out what an 11 request actually does.

Comment: C# (xamarin). In windows form works OK. Problem is with Android

Comment: Is the size of the message the same?  Are you using Net or Core?  The OS interfaces may be different in Windows and Android.  Core was developed to avoid these issues.  Core rewrote the OS interfaces so same code would work on Windows, Linux, and MAC without code changes.  Core made the interfaces the same on all OS.  Maybe use ReadString : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.fromidasync?view=winrt-22621

Comment: I use https://github.com/rostislav-nikitin/Plugin.BluetoothClassic and the question is for people who know this plugin

Comment: Are you using the Release 3 on the link you provided?  Release 3 fixes some enumeration issues.

Comment: This issue is a common issue with communication protocols and not necessarily your plugin.  The link says "through a bluetooth classic protocol".  You may be mixing Classic with a newer version of the protocol.  The library and the OS also need to be consistent. Do not use a library that was designed for a different OS.